# Avoiding data dredging with quasibinomial GLMs

Tags: r, anova, generalized-linear-model, aic, quasi-likelihood

Because my data is a bit overdispersed I am using quasibinomial GLM to analyse them however this means I cannot use AICs to compare my models.
I am therefore using drop1 and update functions to do backward elimination like so.

```
CompMod <- glm(cbind(No.Days.NotEx, No.Days.Ex) ~ Sibling_Count + Waketime + SleepTime + Bedtime + I(Bedtime^2) +
                     Sibling_Count:Waketime + Sibling_Count:SleepTime + Sibling_Count:Bedtime +
                     Sibling_Count:I(Bedtime^2),
                   data = PSD, family = quasibinomial(link = logit))
drop1(CompMod, test="F")
Comp.1 <- update(CompMod, . ~ . - Sibling_Count:SleepTime)
drop1(Comp.1, test="F")
Comp.2 <- update(Comp.1, . ~ . - Sibling_Count:I(Bedtime^2))
drop1(Comp.2, test="F")
Comp.3 <- update(Comp.2, . ~ . - Sibling_Count:SleepTime)
drop1(Comp.3, test="F")
Comp.4 <- update(Comp.3, . ~ . - Sibling_Count:Bedtime)
drop1(Comp..4,test ="F")
Comp.5 <- update(Comp.4, . ~ . - SleepTime)
drop1(Comp.5, test="F")
summary(Comp.5)
Comp.6 <- update(Comp.5, . ~ . - Bedtime)
drop1(Comp.6, test = "F")
Comp.7 <- update(Comp.6, . ~ . - I(Bedtime^2))
drop1(Comp.7, test = "F")
Comp.8 <- update(Comp.7, . ~ . - Sibling_Count:Waketime)
drop1(Comp.8, test = "F")
Comp.9 <- update(Comp.8, . ~ . - Sibling_Count)
summary(Comp.9)
```

Is this a robust method of analysis? I.e. aren't my p values getting deflated whilst doing this- I notice they change quite a lot i.e. the p value for Waketime which is my 'most significant predictor' are non-significant in my first few models then significant in the last few.

My understanding is that the p values from GLMs are only estimates anyway and that to test if a predictor is significant one should do an ANOVA like so;

```
Model 1: cbind(No.Days.NotEx, No.Days.Ex) ~ 1
Model 2: cbind(No.Days.NotEx, No.Days.Ex) ~ Wtime
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance      F  Pr(>F)  
1       115     288.42                             
2       114     281.57  1   6.8577 3.4027 0.06769 .
```

Is this p value (for effect of waketime on No.days exercise/not exercise) trustworthy?

Comment: What is the goal here? Inference or prediction?

Comment: Originally inference but I was considering the possibility of predicting the probability and individual exercises